# Arrays: How to show difference in first and last elements of array and elements of array before a specified index?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm stuck on the following parts:

1. Show the difference between the first and last elements of the array
2. How to show the elements of the array before a specified index in this program ?

**Description of the problem:**

Write a program that makes an array of 25 random integers each from 3 to 7 (use your function randint() to generate these numbers), and includes all the aspects below.

Your program

1. Declares the array in the main (you are not allowed to use global variables!),
2. Initializes the above array to random values 3 to 7 using your randint() function
3. And then calls the functions with the provided prototypes below!

For this, you MUST write the function definitions for the prototypes provided below:

```
void showArray ( int a[ ], int size );      // shows the array in the format "int a [ ] = { 3, 7, 4, ... ,5, 6, 3, 4, 7 } "
void showReverse ( int a[ ], int size );    // shows the array in reverse using the format "int a [ ] = { 7, 4, 3, 6, 5, ... , 4, 7, 3 } "
int  lowest ( int a[ ], int size );         // finds and returns the lowest value in the array (should be 7)
int  highest ( int a[ ], int size );        // finds and returns the highest value in the array (should be 3)
int  sumArray ( int a[ ], int size );       // calculates and returns the sum of all values in the array
float averageVal ( int a[ ], int size );    // calculates and returns the average of all values in the array

int count5 ( int a[ ], int size );           // returns how many times the number 5 appears in the array
int firstMinusLast ( int a[ ], int size );   // returns the difference between the First Array Element - Last Array Element
void showBeforeIndex( int a [ ], int size, int index);  // shows all array values before a specified index
void done ( );                   // a function that shows the message "I am now done with CSS1! :) 
int randint(int min, int max);   // a function that returns a random integer between min and max
```

**Here is my code I have so far --how do I do the array for showing the difference between the first and last array elements and the way to determine show the elements of the array before a specified index (for example, index 3)?**

```
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

void showArray ( int a[ ], int size ); // shows the array in the format "int a [ ] = { 3, 7, 4, ... ,5, 6, 3, 4, 7 } "

void showReverse ( int a[ ], int size );
int  lowest ( int a[ ], int size );
int highest ( int a[ ], int size );
int  sumArray ( int a[ ], int size );
float averageVal ( int a[ ], int size );
int count5 ( int a[ ], int size );                              // returns how many times the number 5 appears in the array
int firstMinusLast ( int a[ ], int size );                      // returns the difference between the First Array Element - Last Array Element
void showBeforeIndex( int a [ ], int size, int index);          // shows all array values before a specified index
void done ();      
int randint(int min, int max);                                  // a function that returns a random integer between min and max

int main ()
{
    srand((int)time(NULL));
    int i = 0;
    const int size = 25; // size variable for arrays
    int randint[size], lowest, highest;


    cout << "Making an array of 25 random integers from 3 to 7!\n";
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "Original array a [ ] = {";

    for(i; i < size; i++)
    {
        randint[i] = 3 + rand () % 5; // random number between 3 to 7
    }

     showArray(randint, size); // pass the array and its SIZE to function
     cout << "}\n";

    // Reversed array
     // One way to reverse an array is to swap the first and last value,
    // then swap the second and second-to-last value,
    // then swap the third and third-to-last value, and so on...
    cout << "\n" << "Reversed array a [ ] = { ";

    int j = size-1; // initialize j to the last index
    i = 0;  // set i to the beginning index (i.e. index 0)

    while( i <= j)  // keep loop until i and j cross over
    {
        std::swap(randint[i], randint[j]); // swap the values at i-th and j-th index
        i++; // move i forwards
        j--; // move j backwards
    }

    showReverse(randint, size);
    cout << "}\n";

    lowest=randint[0];
    highest=randint[0];

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if(randint[i]<lowest)
            lowest=randint[i];
        if(randint[i]>highest)
            highest=randint[i];
    }

    cout<<"\nLowest value is : "<<lowest <<"\n";
    cout<<"\nHighest value is : "<<highest <<"\n";


    int sum=0;


    for (int a=0; a<size; a++)
    {
        sum+=randint[a];
    }

    cout << "\nThe sum of all array elements is " << sum << endl;

    float average=sum/size;

    cout << "\nThe average of all array values is " << average << endl;


    int numsearch = 5;

    int counter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        if(randint[i] == numsearch)
            counter++;
    std::cout << "\nThe number 5 appears " << counter <<" times.\n";

    std::cout << firstMinusLast;

    return 0;
}

// Function definitions
void showArray ( int a[ ], int size )
{
     for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) std::cout << a[i] << " ";
}

void showReverse ( int a[ ], int size )
{
     for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) std::cout << a[i] << " ";

}

int count5(int numsearch, int randint[], int size)
{
    int counter = 0;
    for(int a = 0; a < size; a++)
        if(randint[a] == numsearch)
            counter++;
    return counter;
}

int first (int size)  /// find the first digit
    {
        while (size >=25)
            size /= 25;

        return size;
    }

int last (int size)  /// find the first digit
    {
        return (size%25);
    }

int firstMinusLast ( int a[ ], int size )
{
    int first = -1, last = -1;
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    if (a != rand[i])
        continue;
    if (first == -1)
        first = i;
    last = i;
}
if (first != -1)
    cout << "First minus last = " << first-last;

}

/* SAMPLE RUN:
ERRORS – will not compile; errors say: 
||=== Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown) ===|
|In function 'int firstMinusLast(int*, int)'|
|214|warning: pointer to a function used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]|
|214|error: comparison between distinct pointer types 'int*' and 'int   (__attribute__((__cdecl__)) *)()' lacks a cast [-fpermissive]|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))     
*/
```

Comment: please only show the part of the code where you have trouble with.

Comment: Please provide what you expect vs what you get when you run it.

Comment: Holy crap that's a lot of uneeded code. If you want other people to do your homework for you, at least make it easy for them

Comment: This is actually an exercise and not homework, but if I don't get through this part, I won't be able to understand and finish this part of the course. I'm afraid I don't know how to make it shorter or which is un-needed. I understood everything in C++ up until arrays -- struggling with the last half of this course. :( Anyone have ideas how I can make it better? I'm really not trying to annoy anyone, just want to be sure I understand this!

Comment: Bottom line of what the OP wants is to know :

1. How to find the difference of the first and the last elements of an array.

2. How to show the elements of the array before a specified index in this program ?

@amykp : Isn't this what you want ?

Comment: Yes -- thank you, @VishaalShankar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is quite chaotic and includes pieces of code which are not needed. One thing I can point out however, is that your functions for summing up and averaging the elements of the array seem to have been somehow merged with `main()`.

Please separate them and only **invoke** them in `main()`. (Note that you can use the function for summing to calculate the average).

Regarding your first question, you can calculate the difference between the first and last elements of an array like so:

```
int firstMinusLast(int a[], int size)
{
    return(a[0] - a[size-1]);
}
```

since the first element always bears the index zero and the index of the last element has to be provided anyway.

To show the elements of an array before a specified index, you need to loop through them until your index reaches the specified value:

```
void ShowBeforeIndex(int a[], int size, int index)
{
    for(int Ix = 0; Ix < index; Ix++)
        cout << a[Ix] << " ";
}
```

Note that the size need not be specified as long as you trust the user to invoke the function with a correct index.

Comment: I don't know why I am having so much trouble with arrays! :( When I try to invoke them in main, they don't output...any ideas?

Comment: You don't **invoke** arrays, since arrays are variables, not instructions. You invoke functions (aka methods in OOP).

You may want to consult a real handbook that presents the basics of the language, not online tutorials, which are oftentimes "sketchy". The book I learned C programming from, back in the day, was _C Programming Language_ by Kernighan and Ritchie. It is old but I cannot think of any part of it which has become obsolete; rather, as the language developed,new mechanisms have been added to the content it presents.Have a look and make sure you understand every example shown in it